# Image not displaying and no errors despite <img> tag being present

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, cross-browser

(Repoed on [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/4tGAFuqjfqn9hYUy1Xoa))

I have a page, the user enters a username, website goes and gets some metadata, including the Gravatar ID.  It then uses the ID to display the avatar, however, despite the `img` tag being there, the correct URL being in it and there being no errors in the developer console of the browser the image isn't displayed.

I can also see the HTTP call being made, and returning 200.

---

### NB

If I open the Plunkr in Firefox, I can a reference error:

```
ReferenceError: angular is not defined
http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/4tGAFuqjfqn9hYUy1Xoa/app.js
Line 1
```

### NB

In both IE and Safari it works as expected, only Chrome fails without error.

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="gitHubViewer">
<head lang="en">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script/angular/app.js"></script>
    <script src="script/angular/controllers/main-controller.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-controller="MainController">
    <div>
        <h2>{{user.name}}</h2>
        <div>Username: {{user.login}}</div>
        <div>Gravatar ID: {{user.gravatar_id}}</div>
        <img ng-src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{user.gravatar_id}}" />
    </div>

    <form name="searchUser">
        <input type="search" placeholder="Username to find." ng-model="username" />
        <input type="submit" value="Search" ng-click="search(username)"/>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Main Controller:

```
(function (app) {
    var MainController = function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.message = 'Hello World!';

        $scope.search = function (username) {
            console.log('Username = ' + username);

            $http.get('https://api.github.com/users/' + username)
                .then(onUserComplete);
        };

        var onUserComplete = function (response) {
            $scope.user = response.data;
        };

    };

    app.controller("MainController", ["$scope", "$http", MainController])
})(gitHubViewer);
```

app.js

```
var gitHubViewer = gitHubViewer || angular.module("gitHubViewer", [], function () {
});
```

Comment: I tested your plunkr, it does show the image

Comment: @apairet really?  OK, that adds something.  I'll keep poking about.  What username did you try?

Comment: pkozlowski-opensource for example

Comment: What browsers are you both using?  It works for me on IE & Safari, not on Chrome or Firefox (Firefox throws error, Chrome does not).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, problem solved as far as Chrome goes.  I noticed that I wasn't seeing my profile piccy on here and it turns out [Ghostery](https://www.ghostery.com/en-GB/) blocks [Gravatar](http://www.gravatar.com/) by default.  Whitelisting it solved the problem.

<strike>Firefox seems a little tricky, just tried blatting it and downloading it from the their website and now everything in the world (including it's own add-ons service) is throwing invalid certificate errors.</strike>

Fiddler running without setting up it's certs caused Firefox to throw cert errors, including doing unable to get some JS files on Plunkr.

Answer (score 1):

It works just fine both in Chrome and Firefox.

Chrome Version 36.0.1985.143 m

Firefox 31

Comment: Cheers, what versions did you try?

Comment: Chrome the same, I was using Firefox 30... I'll upgrade. (Totally clutching at straws here)

Comment: I used Firefox 30 too initially. I updated it to 31 when I wanted to check if it works. It worked on both versions.